# How to share variables between different CMakeList.txt?

Tags: c++, cmake

I have a project with multiple `CMakeList.txt`, one for code, one for units tests and 2 other for libraries and I want to share some lines of the `CMakeList.txt` to avoid duplicate like:

`cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0)` or `set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)`

Can I use something like `include("MyProject/CMakeConfig.txt")`?

Comment: Do you have a top-level `CMakeLists.txt` which includes all those sub-projects via `add_subdirectory`? Why not put those common lines to that top-level file?

Comment: The answer is No and Yes.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57638044/can-you-have-a-common-cmake-minimum-included-from-another-file/57638402#57638402

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually, you have one CMake lists file that is at the toplevel of the project and the other used as subdirectories. Since `cmake_minimum_required` and `project` are required once by project, you should be fine writing nothing in your case.

Here's an example of a structure:

Top level `./CMakeLists.txt`:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0)
project(my-project CXX)

# set global property for all this file and subdirectories
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)

# needs to be at the top level
enable_testing()

add_subdirectory(src)
add_subdirectory(test)
```

In `src/CMakeLists.txt`:

```
add_executable(your-exec file1.cpp file2.cpp file3.cpp)
add_library(your-lib file4.cpp file5.cpp file6.cpp)

find_package(liba REQUIRED)

target_link_libraries(your-exec PUBLIC liba::liba)
target_include_directory(...)
# ...
```

In `test/CMakeLists.txt`:

```
find_package(Catch2 REQUIRED)
add_executable(test1 test1.cpp)

# link into you lib and a test framework
target_link_libraries(test1 PRIVATE your-lib Catch2::Catch2) 
add_test(NAME test1 COMMAND test1)
```

All the added subdirectories will inherit the basic properties of the project, such as the minimum CMake version, enabled languages and explicitly set directory based property such as `CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD`.

All that said, it's always a good idea to add C++17 as a requirement to use your project:

```
# All users of your-lib need C++17
target_compile_features(your-lib PUBLIC cxx_std_17)
```